# How do i make all my h2 use the same class without using span? I want all my h2's to use .fancy_underline class

Tags: html, css

How do i make all my h2 use the same class without using span? I want all my h2's to use .fancy_underline class by default. So that whole my site is the same on every h2 heading. I know how i can style my h2 but not how to default a class for h2.

thanks

Comment: Add all your CSS property to h2 from .fancy_underline

Answer (score 2):

You can style directly for `h2 { ... }`.

So if your current css is

```
.fancy_underline {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "roboto", monospace;
    /*more styles...*/
 }
```

just add the h2 tag there along with a comma so that the exisiting styles remain the same.

```
.fancy_underline,
h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "roboto", monospace;
    /*more styles...*/
 }
```

Comment: But this does not make all h2 have the fancy underline. Please check https://woocommerce-466663-1507938.cloudwaysapps.com/ and see the blue fancy underline. I want that to appear on every h2 text.

Comment: I can style directly for h2 the same as fancy-underline and then the blue underline appears on all h2 only thing missing is the position relative for it and i do not know how to het that right for all h2s

Answer (score 0):

Instead of have the class, select your h2 tag in CSS and set it too all properties you have in your class to the h2 you selected